# how to add download image button for mobile

Tags: php, html, wordpress, mobile, download

i made Wordpress website which only contains images and also i have download button implemented in every image which is working very well on desktop site but on mobile phone it doesn't work, here is my code:

```
<a href="<?php
$files = get_children("post_parent=$id&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image");
if($files){
        $keys = array_keys($files);
        $num=$keys[0];
        $thumb=wp_get_attachment_url($num);
        print "$thumb";
}
?>?" download="<?php the_title(); ?>">Download Image</a>
```

can u please tell me if there is another code which will work on smartphone too ? thanks

Comment: You mean it doesn't work on ios? Should work fine on chrome or UC browser in android, as long as the images are from same origin.

Comment: Android users can press and hold on the image. iOS users, meh.. the picked the wrong phone. ;-)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes but i want to make android app and it doesn't allow long press, please can u help ? how to download in android app as i am using webView to build android app